# Storing Month Format on a Database (From Java)

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have an Android app where there is a `spinner` (drop-down) list where I list the next 24 months from the current date.  (The Context:  The user can pick a date in the next two years to schedule a payment).

Currently, I correctly display the current date  (based by locale) in the `spinner` and this is not the problem.  My question is:  What kind of unit should I store for the value of the selection?  The first choice seemed like a `unix timestamp`, but that refers to a specific point in time down to the millisecond and doesn't represent a whole month.  I can't just use a month (for example, 10 is November), because I need the year too.

For example, it is September 2014 as I write this.  If the user wants to schedule a payment two months from now, they would select "Nov 2014" (the format I choose).  *What value can I use in the database that would ALWAYS represent **this** month **in this specific year***?

I fear I am overthinking this.

Here is my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24;i++) {

        Month m = new Month();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        Date date = cal.getTime();

        m.num = date.toString(); // This is where I am trying to store the output - not sure if I am on right track?

   }
```

`Month` is my object I am creating for the `spinner`.  It has two values;  one not shown here that is the readable format, the other is `num` which is my value.

Comment: just use the native Date type for the database you are using... usually it's in the format: 13-Sept-2014... when you query it back out, you can always change the format to whatever is useful for your app.

Comment: @SnakeDoc  I kind of just saw that as well and added some code, am I on the right track?

Comment: You could look at `SimpleDateFormat` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html   -- Don't know if that is in Android or not (probably is), then store it in whatever format you want. For scheduling of things, you may also want to check out the `Quartz Scheduler` library: http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: @SnakeDoc  Thanks, yes I have used `SimpleDateFormat` many times.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do then? If you use `SimpleDateFormat` you can pass in your date object, and get out only the month and year if that is what you are after, then you can write that to a database as a `varchar` or similar text field type, or you can just pass the raw date into a Date field type in the database. Either way, your program will need to read those values and determine if today is that date, so keeping it in a Date type in the database will allow easier querying: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '13-Sept-2014';` or something

Comment: @SnakeDoc  I was just about to ask that. I think I am really overthinking this and can just user the String format as the actual value.

Comment: Only one way to find out ;P  --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Store your date in the database as a varchar using a specific string format. I would represent dates using "yyyy-MM", as this makes it easy to conveniently sort rows by date.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");

// from date to string
String dateString = dateFormatter.format(new Date()); 

// and back
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: That format of four-digit year + hyphen + two-digit month is actually compliant with the [`ISO 8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time strings. By the way, the standard requires the hyphen for that [year+month format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) to avoid confusion with similar formats.

Comment: If you add the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to your project, you can use the [`YearMonth`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) class to represent such a year+month value. That class parses and generates the `yyyy-MM` strings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by trooper is correct and good. Using a string in the format `yyyy-MM` is smart:

- Readable
- Sorting alphabetically is also sorting chronologically
- Complies with the sensible [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time strings.

## Joda-Time

I'm just adding a bit of example code showing how to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library to make use of the [`YearMonth`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) class to represent this year+month meaning, and parse/generate strings.

```
String input = "2014-02";
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse( input ); // Construct by parsing string.
int year = yearMonth.getYear(); 
int month = yearMonth.getMonthOfYear();
String output = yearMonth.toString(); // Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 formats by default for generating strings.
YearMonth yearMonth2 = new YearMonth( year , month ); // Construct by passing numbers for year and month.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "yearMonth: " + yearMonth );
System.out.println( "year: " + year );
System.out.println( "month: " + month );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "yearMonth2: " + yearMonth2 );
```

When run.

```
input: 2014-02
yearMonth: 2014-02
year: 2014
month: 2
output: 2014-02
yearMonth2: 2014-02
```